# Not getting list names as row names in do.call

Tags: r, list, dataframe, do.call

I have a list of data frames, a sample is shown below.

```
list(First = structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 
5, 5.4), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame"), Second = structure(list(
    Sepal.Length = c(6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.3, 
    3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3), Petal.Length = c(5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 
    5.1), Petal.Width = c(2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2, 2.3, 1.8), Species = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F"), class = "data.frame"))
```

I was expecting to get list names as row names on `do.call()`, but I am not getting the expected results. So I want list names as row names after combining.

`do.call(rbind, df)`

Comment: Maybe try: `data.table::rbindlist(df, idcol = "dfID")`

Comment: Please provide the expected output, it is not very clear from your post.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want list names as row names?

Comment: @zx8754 This works. Thank you

Comment: @AgazWani, Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the list names as row names because your data frames already have row names. So you need to first remove the row names and then combine the list.

```
library(tibble)
df <- lapply(df, function(x){
  x <- rownames_to_column(x, var = "col")
}) 
do.call(rbind, df)
```

```
          col Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
First.1    A          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
First.2    B          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
First.3    C          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
First.4    D          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
First.5    E          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
First.6    F          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    setosa
Second.1   A          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
Second.2   B          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
Second.3   C          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
Second.4   D          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
Second.5   E          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
Second.6   F          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst1, .id = 'dfID')
```